# Bad format for number 'gold' in column 1

Tags: java, mysql

I have just started using MySQL today, so please without hate.

This is the table how it looks in phpmyadmin: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4bqL.png
Here is the method I'm using: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCY7U.png
Here is the error I'm getting: "Bad format for number 'gold' in column 1.", it's pointing on this line: return st.getDouble(1);

Thanks for any help!

Comment: just use... select gold... instead of select 'gold'

Comment: *gold* is no *Double*

Comment: Could you add the actual query to the question as text? Image links to external resources may not be very useful for any later readers of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing

```
SELECT 'gold' FROM `Economy` WHERE...
```

That will select the *string literal* 'gold' from the database, not the value of the gold field.

If you want to quote a field name, you need to use backticks;

```
SELECT `gold` FROM `Economy` WHERE...
```

...although the query in this case will work just as well without quoting the field name at all.